# Loading data into BigQuery from GCS (load_table_from_uri) - max files?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm loading a lot of newline delimited json files into BigQuery. By a lot, I mean, each call to `bq_client.load_table_from_uri` passes a list of 1,000 to 1,500 files. So far, it's been working fine. I'm trying to determine if there's a limit to how many files I can send in to this API call. Haven't found any mentions of such limits anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs) for json max file size is Uncompressed 5TB and Maximum row size - 100 MB

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I didn't find that page. What I was looking for was `Maximum number of source URIs in job configuration — 10,000 URIs`